# Python: Dynamically call function within abstract class

Tags: python, python-2.7, abstract-class

I have a class instance that needs to call the analyse method.  The constructor receives the request object with this kind of message

> {
>     "message":{
>         "attributes":{
>             "message_id":"2aj78h98-2112-4637-76h1-09ec727933bb",
>             "topic":"MyTopic",
>             "version":1
>         },
>         "data":"{"id": 123541234}"
>       }
>   }

```
my_model = MyModel(request)
my_model.analyse(data)
```

The structure of the class MyModel is:

```
import importlib


class MyModel(object):

    def __init__(self, req):

        """
        From the request, extract the topic and dynamically create is    instance
        """
        try:
            self.req = req
            classname = self.req.topic # in this example: MyTopic
            classpath = 'foo.bar'
            module = importlib.import_module(classpath)
            self.some_object = getattr(module, classname)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e.message)

    def analyse(self):
        data = self.req.data
        # self.some_object is an instance of foo.bar.MyTopic
        self.some_object.analyse(data)
```

Here is the structure of MyTopic class:

```
class MyTopic(TopicBase):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTopic, self).__init__()
        self.retreive_mode = 'api'

    def _retreive_from_db(self):
        print 'in db'

    def _retreive_from_datawarehouse(self):
        print 'in datawarehouse'

    def _retreive_from_api(self):
       print 'in api
```

and its parent class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class TopicBase(object):
__metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def analyse(self, data):
        """
        Base on the class configuration, call the proper retreive method
        """

        def func_not_found():  # just in case we dont have the method
            raise NotImplementedError

        func_name = '_retreive_from_' + self.retreive_mode
        func = getattr(self, func_name, func_not_found)
        func(data)

    @abstractmethod
    def _retreive_from_db(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _retreive_from_datawarehouse(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _retreive_from_api(self):
        pass
```

When my_model.analyse(data) is called, I get the error:

```
TypeError: unbound method analyse() must be called with MyTopic instance as first argument (got dict instance instead)
```

my_model is already an instance of MyTopic.  So if I try my_model.analyse(my_model, data), I got the error:

```
TypeError: unbound method analyse() must be called with MyTopic instance as first argument (got ABCMeta instance instead)
```

Any idea??

Comment: You're calling the method on the class, not on an instance, and so must pass an instance as the first argument. You don't actually show the code, but my guess is that you are doing `my_model = MyTopic` somewhere rather than `my_model = MyTopic()` so are not actually instantiating the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
self.some_object = getattr(module, classname)
```

sets `self.some_object` to a class (not an instance of that class), which means that when `MyModel.analyse()` calls

```
self.some_object.analyse(data)
```

it's calling `SomeClass.analyse(data)` and not `SomeClass().analyse(data)`.